# How to retrieve error messages from gstreamer? (C API)

Tags: gstreamer, glib

I am trying to initialize a gstreamer pipeline via the C API. The code looks similar to this:

```
[...]

pipeline = (GstPipeline*)gst_pipeline_new(nullptr);
if(!pipeline) {
    //error
    return;
}

[...]

sink     = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", nullptr);
if(!sink) {
    //error
    return;
}

if(!gst_bin_add((GstBin*)pipeline, sink)) {
    //error
    return;
}

[...]

GstBus* bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(pipeline);
gst_bus_add_watch(bus, (GstBusFunc)bus_callback, this);
gst_object_unref(bus);

GstStateChangeReturn state = gst_element_set_state((GstElement*)pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

if(!state) {
    //error2
    return;
}
[...]
```

Although errors appear in the cout I would like to retrieve the errors as a C string (or any format that I can process). How do I do that?

I have read that errors are posted to the bus of the pipeline, yet when calling gst_element_set_state my bus callback isn't called. Maybe because the glib main loop is not running yet?

Sorry, I am pretty new to the gstreamer/glib libraries and I couldn't find a clear answer in the (overwhelming) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set a listener which receives messages and checks for errors. Example: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html. (GError is the data type used for errors.)